# Select Top Row in a Group By without any numerical aggregation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to build a Item Table in access.  I have item number, mfg name, and product description.  I would like my PK to be item number and mfg name.  However, I have about 5k areas where the product description is creating duplicates based on a slight variation in the description itself.  I would like to just have access create the table by grouping all items based on item number and mfg name and then select the first result.

NOTE: the method I have attempted below uses MIN/MAX.  This does NOT have to be the method suggested.  Ultimate goal is to select the top row or a single row for each group  So if i have 2 part numbers that say 123 and 2 product descriptions for that part number, I just want one of those descriptions to display.  It does NOT matter which one.

Example:

> Item_Num, MFG_Name, Product_Desc
>
> 414001000,    AMBU INC.,  ASCOPE 3,LARGE,5.8/2.8  5EA/BX
>
> 414001000,     AMBU INC.,     ASCOPE 3,LARGE,5.8/2.8 5EA/BX
>
> 06L21-01,  ABBOTT LABORATORIES INC,    07K0040AT HAVAB-M CALB 4ML  RX
>
> 06L21-01,  ABBOTT LABORATORIES INC,    ARCHITECT HAVAB-M CALB 4ML  RX

Ideally, this is my result:

> Item_Num, MFG_Name, Product_Desc
>
> 414001000,    AMBU INC.,  ASCOPE 3,LARGE,5.8/2.8  5EA/BX
>
> 06L21-01,  ABBOTT LABORATORIES INC,    07K0040AT HAVAB-M CALB 4ML  RX

Idea so far that I have is to count the length of the description to quantify.  Then use min/max to select the one that is desired.  My code so far is:

```
SELECT
x.distributor_item_number, 
x.mfg_item_number, 
x.mfg_name, 
x.distributor_product_description, 
min(x.[LENGTH OF DESC]) 

INTO Product_Table
FROM [Product Table] AS x 

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT p.distributor_item_number, 
max(p.[LENGTH OF DESC]) AS [MAX LENGTH] 
FROM [Product Table] AS p 
GROUP BY p.distributor_item_number)  AS y ON (y.distributor_item_number = x.distributor_item_number) AND (y.[MAX LENGTH] = X.[LENGTH OF DESC])

GROUP BY x.distributor_item_number, x.mfg_item_number, x.mfg_name, x.distributor_product_description;
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working.  I am still having duplicates in the data.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: *use min/max to select the one that is desired* which is desired? The one with minimum or maximum length?

Comment: There could be more than 1 with the same min/max length.

Comment: It honestly does not matter which length.  Ultimate goal is to select 1 per group.  This is an attempt to standardize the table where the table has duplicate values in the description.  Thanks

Comment: Is *distributor_item_number* unique to every *distributor_product_description*? If not, what is relationship between *distributor_item_number* and *mfg_item_number*? Please also show undesired results as you mention *I am still having duplicates in the data*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a sequencing number in the select statement that would sequence for each group.  Then I just selected the first row of each sequence.  Code below

```
SELECT 

p1.mfg_item_number, 
p1.mfg_name, 
p1.distributor_product_description,
Count(*) AS Seq

INTO Clean_Product_Table

FROM Product_Table AS p1 

INNER JOIN Product_Table AS p2 ON (p2.mfg_item_number = p1.mfg_item_number) 
                               AND (P2.MFG_NAME = P1.MFG_NAME) 
                               AND (p2.InoSeq <= p1.InoSeq)

GROUP BY p1.mfg_item_number, 
         p1.mfg_name, 
         p1.distributor_product_description

HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY 1, 2, 5;
```